# Need some help showing that: $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \backslash B(0,k)} f d\lambda ^n = 0$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Assignment: I would like to verify this attempt

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a real function Lebesgue integrable. Show that:

> $ \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \backslash B(0,k)} f d\lambda ^n = 0$

Proof: Let $A=\mathbb{R}^n \backslash B(0,k) $
And let S be a rectangle that contains A, and let us extend each of the functions $f_k$, and also f, to S, setting them to zero at S \ A.

Then these extensions have the property that $f_k$ converges to $f$ uniformly in S. For each $k ∈ N$

Now let $D_k$ be the set of points of discontinuity of the function $f_k$ (extended) and let

$G := S \backslash \cup_{k=1}^{∞} D_k.$

It is evident that all functions $f_k$ are continuous in $G$, and furthermore $f_k$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $G ⊆ S$. Then, since the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions in a set is continuous in that set, we have that $f$ is continuous in $G$. Therefore, the set $D$ of the points of discontinuity of f is contained in $S \backslash G = \cup_{k=1}^{∞} D_k$, which has zero measure because it is a countable union of sets of zero measure (the $D_k$ have zero measure because each $f_k$ is integrable). Then $D$ also has zero measure and so $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Did you mean $f$ Lebesgue *integrable*? Otherwise take $f\equiv 1$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I've already corrected the hypothesis

Comment: I don't understand what your proof is for. It seems like you're proving that the set of discontinuities of $f$ is of measure zero (which need not be true BTW: think of Dirichlet's function), and then conclude $f$ is (Riemann?) integrable?

Comment: What I was meant is that is integrable and it's equal to zero, but still I'm not sure of how its done

Comment: What is your $f$ in the proof? $f$ is given as a Lebesgue integrable function from the beginning, but otherwise arbitrary. So, like in Jose27's comment, I am not sure what you are trying to check. Also, is the dominated convergence theorem available to you?

Comment: Yes, it is permitted. And $f$ is a function to which the $f_n$ are supposed to converge

Comment: First, you are overriding a new meaning to $f$, because $f$ is given in at the beginning of the statement. That will certainly cause confusion among those who reads your proof. You may consider calling the limit by other symbol. Second, note in fact that $$ \lim_{k\to\infty} f(x)\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(0,k)}(x) = 0 \quad\text{for all}\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^n, $$ where $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the [indicator function notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). This is simply because $x\notin B(0,k)$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: Then apply the dominated convergence theorem to $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(0,k)} f \, \mathrm{d}\lambda^n = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(0,k)} \, \mathrm{d}\lambda^n . $$ (Check that DCT is indeed applicable. It is supposed to be easy to verify.)

Comment: Then taking the limits when $k \rightarrow \infty$, the integral would be equal to zero, right?

Comment: What does "rectangle" mean for you?  Usually it involves having sides of finite length, in which case your proof breaks down immediately because there is no rectangle that contains the unbounded set $A$.  Also there is no need whatsoever to look at points of discontinuity.